# Magento 2 : Message manager not working

Tags: magento2, messages, success-message

In Magento 2.3.3, I save form data by ajax and need to display success message after save records.

> **Expected Result :**

Message manager should be display.

> **Actual Result :**

Message manager not display. It will display after page reload.

> **Controller code :**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Magento\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Session
     */
    protected $adminsession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context        $context           [description]
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory [description]
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Session $adminsession
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->adminsession = $adminsession;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        /** Save Logic */
        try {
                $object->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Data has been saved.'));
                //$this->messageManager->addMessages($this->messageManager->getMessages(true));
                //$this->messageManager->setMessages($this->messageManager->getMessages(true));
                $this->adminsession->setFormData(false);
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the data.'));
            }
            $this->_getSession()->setFormData($postData);
    }
}
```

> **Note :** I don't want to set message using jQuery.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.